# Move Gimp on the top of list in Screenshot

Tags: screenshot, print-screen

When I press PrtSc button, in the Screenshot dialog, if I choose "open with" in appear list, gimp is always on the bottom. Is it possible to move on the top?

[image]

Comment: What app do you use for screenshot to have such an option "open with". The default [`gnome-screenshot`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-screenshot/) doesn't have this option. Can you post a screenshot eventually?

Comment: [http://i44.tinypic.com/1sijd1.jpg]

Comment: There's no way you can reorder that list without editing the source of the program and recompiling it.

Comment: It's xubuntu default, not ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I just made new shortcut of app

```
xfce4-screenshooter -or gimp
```

and now simple click automaticly opens screenshot in gimp